# cpp compare_exchange_strong fails spuriously?

Tags: c++, atomic, pool

So I'm pretty new to CPP and i was trying to implement a resource pool (SQLITE connections), for a small project that I'm developing.

The problem is that I have a list(vector) with objects created at the beginning of the program, that have the given connection and its availability (atomic_bool). If my program requests a connection from this pool, the following function gets executed:

```cpp
gardener_db &connection_pool_inner::get_connection() {
    bool expected = false;

    for(auto & pair : pool) {
        std::atomic_bool &ref = pair->get_is_busy_ref();
        if (ref.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) {
            return pair->get_conn();
        }//if false it means that its busy
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(vector_mutex);//increment size
    std::atomic_bool t = true;
    pool.emplace_back(std::make_shared<pool_elem>());
    pool.back()->get_is_busy_ref().store(t);// because we are giving the resource to the caller
    return pool.back()->get_conn();
}
```

So I made a simple test to see if my vector is resizing:

```
constexpr unsigned int CONNECTION_POOL_START_SIZE = 20;
TEST(testConnPool, regrow) {
    auto saturation = std::vector<connection_handler>();
    ASSERT_EQ(saturation.size(), 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < CONNECTION_POOL_START_SIZE; i++) {
        saturation.emplace_back();
    }
    auto ptr = connection_pool_inner::instance();
    auto size = ptr->get_pool().size();

    //it  should be full at this point
    ASSERT_EQ(size, CONNECTION_POOL_START_SIZE);
}
```

the problem is that I get 22 as my size as opposed to 20 which is what I would expect.

I was able to narrow down the problem to the compare_exchage_strong() but, it was my understanding that the "strong" variant wouldn't fail. So I debugged it, and its always the third element of my vector that gets skipped, (even when working on a single thread).

I already test it the same thing on a different computer(and architecture) but the same problem still occurs so I'm guessing the problem is the logic.

Any ideas about what's going on?

## MRE

```
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class foo {
    std::atomic_bool inner;
public:
    explicit foo(): inner(false){};
    std::atomic_bool &get(){return inner;}
};

std::mutex vector_mutex;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo>> resources;

void get_resource() {
    bool expected = false;
    for(auto & rsc : resources) {
        if (rsc->get().compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(vector_mutex);//increment size
    resources.emplace_back(std::make_shared<foo>());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo>> *local = &resources;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        resources.emplace_back(std::make_shared<foo>());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        get_resource();
    }
    std::cout << resources.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code results in undefined behavior in a multithreaded environment.

While the loop `for(auto & pair : pool)` is runing in one thread, `pool.emplace_back(std::make_shared<pool_elem>())` in another thread invalidates `pool` iterators that are used in the running loop under the hood.

You have the error in the loop.
[std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange):

> <...> loads the actual value stored in `*this` into `expected` (performs load operation).

Let's vector `busy` to be a conditional name for busy states.
The first `get_connection()` call results in the vector `busy` to be `{ true, false, ... false }`.

The second `get_connection()` call:

1. `expected = false;`
2. `busy[0]` is `true` is not equal to `expected`, it gets `expected = true;`
3. `busy[1]` is `false` is not equal to the updated `expected`, it gets `expected = false;`
4. `busy[2]` is `false` is equal to the updated `expected`, results in the vector `busy` to be `{ true, false, true, false, ... false }`.

The further 8 `get_connection()` calls result in the vector `busy` to be `{ (true, false) * 10 }`.

The 11th and 12th `get_connection()` calls add yet a couple of `true` and result in the vector `busy` to be `{ (true, false) * 10, true, true }`, the size is 22.

Other `get_connection()` calls do not modify the vector anymore:

0. <...>
1. `busy[10]` is `true` is not equal to `expected`, it gets `expected = true;`
2. `busy[11]` is `true` is equal to the updated `expected`, return.

The fix

```
// bool expected = false;  ───────┐
//                                │
for(auto & pair : pool) {   //    │
    bool expected = false;  // ◄──┘
    std::atomic_bool &ref = pair->get_is_busy_ref();
    if (ref.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true)) {
        return pair->get_conn();
    }//if false it means that its busy
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know that,  i thought the mutex would prevent that, i guess it doesn't. I'll fix that. Anyways I dont think that might be the problem, since the test is only running in a single thread.

Comment: loads the actual value stored in *this into expected (performs load operation). >> oh that makes sense, I didn't know that, ok thank you. Ill try to update the question with the MRE. Regards